# Laravel Eloquent update with custom entries

Tags: laravel, eloquent, crud

I have u CRUD project, and now I have idea to get update of one table with custom entries.

This is my controller:

```
 public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->only(['x', 'y', 'time']);

    $device_new = Device_new::where('deviceId', $id)->first();
    $device_new->x = $data['x'];
    $device_new->y = $data['y'];
    $device_new->datetime = $data['datetime'];

    $device_new->save();
}
```

Is it even possible to update x, y, and datetime without edit blade, just update them with some limited values with command on some button?

Like in new controller:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $x='47'; $y='16';

    $device_new = Device_new::where('deviceId', $id)->first();
    $device_new->x = $x;
    $device_new->y = $y;

    $device_new->save();
}
```

Comment: Wrap the button in a form with hidden values would a the easiest approach.

Comment: Is it possible to write command in controller that would generate some entries and use them for update?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Can I make option in controller to for updating all id's at the same time? And I want to update them with specified numbers.